# How do I display the contents of an array without having the "0"'s in the display using a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

```
     public partial class frmEnhancedInvoiceTotal : Form
{
    public frmEnhancedInvoiceTotal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    decimal[] decTotalofInvoicesArray = new decimal[5];
    int intNumberOfInvoices = 0; //global variables 
    decimal decTotalOfInvoicesVariable = 0m;
    decimal decAverageOfInvoices = 0m;


    private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Convert = Class, .ToDecimal = method,
        //when the user clicks the calulate button,
        //we collect the subtotal, determine the appropriate discount,
        //calculate the total and output the result to the screen. 
        //***EARN PARTIAL CREDIT PUT COMMENTS***

        //Input

        try
        {
            decimal decSubtotal = 0m; //initialize subtotal with a value of zero. We'll collect from the user later.
            if (Decimal.TryParse(txtSubtotal.Text,
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, //now can type a $ sign and now break the code 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                out decSubtotal))  //.tryparse attempts to convert but is a fail safe
                                   //parse does 2 things - does something and tells you if works 

                decTotalofInvoicesArray[intNumberOfInvoices] = decSubtotal;

            {
                //Processing
                decimal decDiscountPercent = 0m; //defining a new variable (discount percent) allow for real #, giving it a intial value of 0. Decimal variables you have to add m

                if (decSubtotal >= 500m) //if my subtotal is 500 or more
                {
                    decDiscountPercent = 0.2m; //inside braces is what will happen to the question above 
                                               //set discount rate to 20%
                }
                else if (decSubtotal < 500m && decSubtotal >= 250m) //if subtotal is between 250 & 500
                                                                    //^^redundant because < 500 is already stated in the first if statement 
                                                                    //could just right else if(decSubtotal >=250m)
                {
                    decDiscountPercent = 0.15m; //set discount rate to 15%
                }


                else if (decSubtotal < 250m && decSubtotal >= 100m) //if subtotal is between 100 and 250
                {
                    decDiscountPercent = 0.1m; //set discount to 10%
                }


                //if subtotal is less than 100, dicounter percent is 0%

                decimal decDiscountAmount = decDiscountPercent * decSubtotal;
                decimal decTotal = decSubtotal - decDiscountAmount; //He is going so fast




                //Aggregate Processing - across mutliple clicks of the calculate button

                //old way of doing it = intNumberOfInvoices = intNumberOfInvoices + 1;
                intNumberOfInvoices++; //value of variable plus one

                //old way of doing it decTotalOfInvoices = decTotalOfInvoices + decTotal;
                decimal decSum = 0m;
                for (int intColIndex = 0; intColIndex < decTotalofInvoicesArray.Length; intColIndex++)
                {
                    decSum += decTotalofInvoicesArray[intColIndex];
                }
                decTotalOfInvoicesVariable = decSum;
                decAverageOfInvoices = decSum / decTotalofInvoicesArray.Length;



                //Output 
                txtSubtotal.Text = decSubtotal.ToString("c");
                txtDiscountPercent.Text = decDiscountPercent.ToString("p2"); //sending a numeric value and sending it to text = gives error 
                txtDiscountAmount.Text = decDiscountAmount.ToString("c");    //dot ToString makes value a text value and sends to textbox in form
                                                                             //c=currency    //"p2" - 2 = how many decimal places 
                                                                             //P = percentage 
                txtTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("c");



                //aggregate output
                txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = intNumberOfInvoices.ToString();
                txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = decTotalOfInvoicesVariable.ToString("c");
                txtAverageOfInvoices.Text = decAverageOfInvoices.ToString("c");

                //breakpoint analysis = click on the grey side bar and slowly work through the code to find the error. Essentially pause the code and run the code one point at a time  
            }

        }

         catch (FormatException) //you do not know what went wrong in the try part. It just errors anyways because SOMETHING went wrong 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid numeric values.", "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (OverflowException) //something is to big 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please try smaller numbers", "Entry Error");
        }
        catch //generic error code because why not 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occured. Please try again.", "Entry Error");
        }

    }

    private void BtnClearTotals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When resetting aggregate/global info - need to reset the variables AND the visual interface
        intNumberOfInvoices = 0;
        decTotalOfInvoicesVariable = 0m;
        decAverageOfInvoices = 0m;

        //  txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = ""; //setting the variable to nothing. Erase the information in the text box 
        txtNumberOfInvoices.Clear();
        txtTotalOfInvoices.Clear();
        txtAverageOfInvoices.Clear();
    }

    private void TxtSubtotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDiscountPercent.Clear();
        txtDiscountAmount.Clear();
        txtTotal.Clear();
    }

    private void BtnDisplayTotals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strOrderTotals = "";
        //for (int intColIndex = 0; intColIndex < intNumberOfInvoices; intColIndex++)
        //{
        //    strOrderTotals += decTotalofInvoicesArray[intColIndex] + "\n";
        //}


        foreach (decimal decTotalInvoices in decTotalofInvoicesArray)
        {
            if (strOrderTotals == "0")
            {
                strOrderTotals += decTotalInvoices + "\n";
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(strOrderTotals.ToString());
    }

    private bool IsValidData()
    {
        return
            IsPresent(txtSubtotal) && //did you type anyting
            IsDecimal(txtSubtotal) && //make sure you types a real number
            IsWithinRange(txtSubtotal, 0m, 1000m); //is the number in the range
    }

    private bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox) //send an entire textbox into method
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox.Tag.ToString() + " is a required field.", "Missing Entry"); //textbox is whatever is in the (TextBox textBox)
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool IsDecimal(TextBox textBox)
    {
        decimal decTestValue = 0m;
        if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, out decTestValue)) //! - dont succusfully tryparse
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox.Tag.ToString() + " must be a numeric value", "Entry Error"); //textbox is whatever is in the (TextBox textBox)
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool IsInteger(TextBox textBox)
    {
        int intTestValue = 0;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out intTestValue)) //! - dont succusfully tryparse
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox.Tag.ToString() + " must be a whole number.", "Missing Entry"); //textbox is whatever is in the (TextBox textBox)
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool IsWithinRange(TextBox textBox, decimal decMin, decimal decMax)
    {
        decimal decTestValue = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
        if (decTestValue < decMin || decTestValue > decMax) //to small or to big
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox.Tag.ToString() + " must be between " + decMin.ToString() + " and " + decMax.ToString() + "." + "Out of Range"); //textbox is whatever is in the (TextBox textBox)
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Basically I have a invoice total windows form were the user inputs a subtotal value and total value is calculated based on the discount percent. In the assignment is says to create an array that hold up to five invoice totals. My problem is when I type lets say 2 subtotal values and click display totals the 2 number I typed in are displayed along with 3 zeros. I am wanting to know how to only display the number I inputted and not the zeros using a foreach loop.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Both loops are doing different things, neither of which is what your title describes.

Comment: why you don't use this `var strOrderTotals = string.Join("\n", decTotalofInvoicesArray);` ?

Comment: maybe you got that if statement wrong at,if (strOrderTotals == "0"), or in msgbox, try to substr like strOrderTotals.ToString().Substring(1); to avoid first "0"

Comment: It is not necessary to call `.ToString()` on a variable that is already a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are adding anything in your foreach.

```
foreach (decimal decTotalInvoices in decTotalofInvoicesArray)
{
    if (strOrderTotals == "0")
    {
        strOrderTotals += decTotalInvoices + "\n";
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(strOrderTotals.ToString());
```

Am I reading this right that you want to have each invoice shown, and do you want the total too? This code with a for loop should work. I

```
        strOrderTotals = "My Invoices\n";
        decimal decOrderTotals = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < decTotalofInvoicesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (decTotalofInvoicesArray[i] != 0)
            {
                strOrderTotals += "Invoice : " + decTotalofInvoicesArray[i] + "\n";
                decOrderTotals += decTotalofInvoicesArray[i];
            }
        }
        strOrderTotals += "Total of invoices: " + decOrderTotals;
        MessageBox.Show(strOrderTotals.ToString());
```